# Angular dynamic creation of Directives

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have page setup where I want to dynamically create directives and add them to the page.  I have gotten this work, but in the Directives that I'm adding are not getting compiled correctly because no interpolation is occurring and the Dependency in the constructor is not getting loaded.

Here is the code that I'm using.

page.html

```
<dashboard-dynamic-component ng-repeat="item in vm.parts" dashboard-part="item.part.implementationComponent" dashboard-part-id="item.id"</dashboard-dynamic-component>
```

dashboardDynamicComponent

```
function dynamicComponent($compile: ng.ICompileService, $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/main/dashboard/dynamicComponent.html',
        scope: {
            dashboardPart: '=',
            dashboardPartId: '='
        },
        link: (scope, element) => {
            var newElement = $compile(`<${scope.dashboardPart} dashboard-part-id="${scope.dashboardPartId}" />`)(scope);
            element.append(newElement);
            $timeout(() => {});
        }
    }

}
dynamicComponent.$inject = ['$compile', '$timeout'];

angular.module('Cranalytics')
    .directive('dashboardDynamicComponent', dynamicComponent);
```

This creating the component that I expect it to, but then in the next part is were I see the problems.

titleComponent.html - Which is what is dynamically being created above

```
<h3 class="title">****{{vm.title}}****</h3>
```

titleComponent.ts

```
export class TitleComponent implements ng.IDirective {

    restrict = 'E';
    replace = true;
    templateUrl = 'app/main/dashboard/titleComponent/titleComponent.html';
    scope = {
        dashboardPartId: '='
    };
    controller = TitleController;
    controllerAs = 'vm';
    bindToController = true;

    static create(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        const directive = () => new TitleComponent();
        return directive;
    }
    static instance(): ng.IDirective { return new TitleComponent(); }
}

export class TitleController {

    _dashboardPartId: number;
    get dashboardPartId(): number {
        return this._dashboardPartId;
    }
    set dashboardPartId(value: number) {
        this._dashboardPartId = value;
        if (!value) return;

        this.dataService.loadById(value)
            .then((result: Models.Dashboard.dashboardPart) => {
                var options = JSON.parse(result.options);
                this.title = options.Title;
            });
    }

    title: string;

    static $inject = ['Cranalytics.Dashboard.dashboardPartDataService'];
    constructor(private dataService: Dashboard.dashboardPartDataService) {}
}

angular.module('Cranalytics')
    .directive('dashboardTitleComponent', TitleComponent.create());
```

So I think I'm just missing one little piece because I am getting the ***{{vm.title}}*** on the page, but the interpolation is not displaying and also in the constructor in the above code the dependency for Cranalytics.Dashboard.dashboardPartDataService is returning undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I had was that the property setter for dashboardPartId was being called before the constructor was being called, which resulted in the who component erroring out because this.dataService was undefined.  Once I refactored the loading out of the set and checked for the dataService and added that same call into the constructor everything worked.